# tkinter text widget not able to appear on desired window

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

So i have written a simple tkinter gui that will show some command output results when prompted, only issue i'm having is the command wont appear on any other screen.

```
def updateipt():
    text = Text(main_window, height=150, width=124)
    text.pack()
    with Popen(["iptables", '-L', '-v', '-n'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            text.insert(END, line,)
```

text = Text(main_window, height=150, width=124)

i assumed that replacing the main_window argument above with another window would direct the text widget to a different window, but everytime i try this i get an error Which states that the window needs to be Tk(): AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk'

How do i work around this?

Full code posted below:

```
#!/bin/bash
import os
import subprocess as sub
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def main_window():
    global main_window
    main_window = Tk()
    main_window.title("Firewall test")
    main_window.geometry("1000x700")
    main_window.configure(bg="dark grey")
    label1 = Label(main_window, text="What Would you like to configure?", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bg="white",
                   fg="black")
    label1.pack(fill=X, pady=20)

    btnproc = Button(main_window, text="Process configuration", font=('arial', 9, 'bold'), bg="light grey", fg="black",
                     width="30", height="2", command=lambda: process_window())
    btnproc.pack(pady=20)
    btnfw = Button(main_window, text="Firewall", font=('arial', 9, 'bold'), bg="light grey", fg="black", width="30",
                   height="2", command=lambda: firewall_window())
    btnfw.pack(pady=20)
    btnmon = Button(main_window, text="AIDE", font=('arial', 9, 'bold'), bg="light grey", fg="black", width="30",
                    height="2", command=lambda: monitor_window())
    btnmon.pack(pady=20)

    main_window.mainloop()


def process_window():
    global process_window
    process_window = Toplevel(main_window)
    process_window.title("Process Configuration")
    process_window.geometry("800x600")
    process_window.configure(bg="dark grey")
    label1 = Label(process_window, text="What Would you like to configure?", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bg="white",
                   fg="black")
    label1.pack(fill=X, pady=20)



def firewall_window():
    firewall_window = Toplevel(main_window)
    firewall_window.title("Firewall Configuration")
    firewall_window.geometry("1000x600")
    firewall_window.configure(bg="dark grey")
    label1 = Label(firewall_window, text="What Would you like to configure?", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bg="white",
                   fg="black")
    label1.pack(fill=X, pady=20)

    updatebtn = Button(firewall_window, text="View Current Iptables layout", font=('arial', 9, 'bold'), bg="light grey",
                       fg="black", width="30",
                       height="2", command=lambda: updateipt())
    updatebtn.pack(pady=20)


def monitor_window():
    monitor_window = Toplevel(main_window)
    monitor_window.title("AIDE Configuration")
    monitor_window.geometry("800x600")
    monitor_window.configure(bg="dark grey")
    label1 = Label(monitor_window, text="What Would you like to configure?", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bg="white",
                   fg="black")
    label1.pack(fill=X, pady=20)


def updateipt():
    text = Text(firewall_window, height=150, width=124)
    text.pack()
    with Popen(["iptables", '-L', '-v', '-n'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            text.insert(END, line,)




main_window()
```

Comment: Why do you pass the function name as the parent of `Text()` inside `updateipt()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the name of your functions are **also the name of your windows (Toplevel)**. Please change all your function names. Also, in your `updateipt` function, you are giving a function to place the Text widget so it throws an error.

```
import os
import subprocess as sub
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def main_windows():
    global main_window
    main_window = Tk()
    main_window.title("Firewall test")
    main_window.geometry("1000x700")
    main_window.configure(bg="dark grey")
    label1 = Label(main_window, text="What Would you like to configure?", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bg="white",
                   fg="black")
    label1.pack(fill=X, pady=20)

    btnproc = Button(main_window, text="Process configuration", font=('arial', 9, 'bold'), bg="light grey", fg="black",
                     width="30", height="2", command=lambda: process_windows())
    btnproc.pack(pady=20)
    btnfw = Button(main_window, text="Firewall", font=('arial', 9, 'bold'), bg="light grey", fg="black", width="30",
                   height="2", command=lambda: firewall_windows())
    btnfw.pack(pady=20)
    btnmon = Button(main_window, text="AIDE", font=('arial', 9, 'bold'), bg="light grey", fg="black", width="30",
                    height="2", command=lambda: monitor_windows())
    btnmon.pack(pady=20)

    main_window.mainloop()


def process_windows():
    global process_window
    process_window = Toplevel()
    process_window.title("Process Configuration")
    process_window.geometry("800x600")
    process_window.configure(bg="dark grey")
    label1 = Label(process_window, text="What Would you like to configure?", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bg="white",
                   fg="black")
    label1.pack(fill=X, pady=20)



def firewall_windows():
    firewall_window = Toplevel()
    firewall_window.title("Firewall Configuration")
    firewall_window.geometry("1000x600")
    firewall_window.configure(bg="dark grey")
    label1 = Label(firewall_window, text="What Would you like to configure?", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bg="white",
                   fg="black")
    label1.pack(fill=X, pady=20)

    updatebtn = Button(firewall_window, text="View Current Iptables layout", font=('arial', 9, 'bold'), bg="light grey",
                       fg="black", width="30",
                       height="2", command=lambda: updateipt())
    updatebtn.pack(pady=20)


def monitor_windows():
    monitor_window = Toplevel(main_window)
    monitor_window.title("AIDE Configuration")
    monitor_window.geometry("800x600")
    monitor_window.configure(bg="dark grey")
    label1 = Label(monitor_window, text="What Would you like to configure?", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bg="white",
                   fg="black")
    label1.pack(fill=X, pady=20)


def updateipt():
    text = Text(main_window, height=150, width=124)
    text.pack()
    with Popen(["iptables", '-L', '-v', '-n'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            text.insert(END, line)

    



main_windows()
```